# Facebook Javascript SDK feed doesnt contain status updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is the code for fetching the activity feed from Facebook Javascript SDK

```
function fetchFeed(){
 FB.api("/" + {My-User-ID} + "/feed?limit=5", function (response) {
            if (response.error) {
                console.log("Error fetching feed");
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

}

But the feed obtained doesn't fetch me the status updates from my account , it fetches my other activities like page likes but not the status update .

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because your Access Token is missing some of the permissions required to obtain the user statuses. These permissions are `user_status` and `read_stream`. If you are using Javascript SDK for authentication, you can ask for extra permission in the code using:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'user_status,read_stream'});
```

You can always test your code using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/feed?limit=50&fields=message). It gives you flexibility to manually choose the permissions and test you queries.

PS: If you are only concerned about the statuses, you can use API endpoint like `/{user-id}/status` and `/{user-id}/posts` to narrow down your results. Take a look at the [documentation on /{user_id} edges](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/#edges) to find out the difference among these edges.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rahil for the suggestion , The Graph API Explorer Page helped me to find out the solution, my app (PI CONTROL) didn't have the right permissions in its access token to fetch status updates . LAter Obtained a new access token with right permissions for my application. The steps are depicted in the screenshots below

1.Go to the Graph Explorer Page [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

2.Select the app for which you want to give the permissions for 
[image]

2.Click on **Get Access Token**
[image]

3.Select the right permissions for your app
[image]